# Magento checkbox layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

One of my client need to select multiple values in magento layered navigation using checkboxes for product weight options . How can I do this by coding without using any extensions ? I'm using magento 1.9

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:
1. rewrite catalog/layer/view block to show check boxes
2. rewrite the catalog/layer/model/filter/item to modify URLs
3. rewrite catalog/layer/model/filter/attribute to create the new query, based on multiple attribute options.

Comment: hi yes I have tried those and able to resolve it , thanks for the input

Comment: @Amasty what code needs to be changed, can you please tell us?